# Cocos-2d : memory leak during ReplaceScene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have two Levels level1.mm and level2.mm

In Level1.mm i use button named **"skip level"** MenuItem to Replacescene to go to level2.mm ,But when that method gets called, my app crashes with exec bad access.

But if i use PushScene its going to level2 scenes properly.But I know somewhere memory will be waste if i use pushscene.

What is the bestway to replace scene?should i call any dealloc before replacescene or it will be called automatically?

note : Please Be gentle this is my first game in iphone :) :)

Comment: Need more info about the crash such as the actual log but you can have a read of this and it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881805/when-we-should-use-pushscene-and-replacescene

Comment: Use Replacescene to go to scene2.If You use PushScene it will be stored in stack queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that replaceScene crashes but pushScene does not tells me that the first scene has some kind of issue when it is being deallocated. So your question isn't about how to replace scenes, but rather how to find and fix the bug that causes the crash.

[Try this tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/) to learn more about debugging with Xcode. And since you're new, [you probably aren't using ARC yet](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/). Do that now because it'll help to avoid a ton of similar issues.